# PowerShell How to use -and in Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I want to filter a command result using two conditions. Here are my commands

```
 $list=Get-PnpDevice | Sort-Object -Property Name | Where-Object -Property ConfigurationFlags -NotLike '*DISABLED*' | ft Name, InstanceId -AutoSize
```

and the next filter is

```
 $list=Get-PnpDevice | Sort-Object -Property Name | Where-Object -Property FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*' | ft Name, InstanceId -AutoSize
```

both of them works separately but I want to join them using `and` command. I tried to use `-AND` as following command but it keeps raising errors

```
 Get-PnpDevice | Sort-Object -Property Name | Where-Object{
      ( ConfigurationFlags -NotLike '*DISABLED*') -and 
      ( FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*' ) }| ft Name, InstanceId -AutoSize
```

Comment: please, unless you will ONLY send your info to the screen or a text file, **_do not use the `Format-` cmdlets._** use `Select-Object` instead. ///// why? because they butcher your objects and send the ragged remnants out wrapped in formatting code. try sending the `Format-` output to a $Var and then stepping thru the resulting array one item at a time. the 2nd or 3rd item will show lots or red errors because of the formatting code. [*grin*] ///// 'Select-Object', on the other hand, gives you objects, not formatting code wrapped around butchered bits of your objects.

Comment: Don **NOT** use a `Format-*` cmdlet if you intend to further process the data, you'll get unwanted formatting properties in your variable. Use Select to reduce properties.

Comment: @LotPings thanks for your comment, acctuly I dont need to print them, I want to check number of them and if that device is disabled I enable it, So Select-object is better?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks, can you please give me an example ?

Comment: @MajidHojati - an example of what? [*grin*] the help file for `Select-Object` is really quite good ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the The `$_` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6#examples) in your `Where-Object` to reference the property names:

```
Get-PnpDevice | Sort-Object -Property Name | Where-Object{
      ( $_.ConfigurationFlags -NotLike '*DISABLED*') -and 
      ( $_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*' ) }| ft Name, InstanceId -AutoSize
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe 'Where' clauses together... it's simpler syntax and easier to read

```
Get-PnpDevice | Sort-Object -Property Name | Where ConfigurationFlags -NotLike '*DISABLED*' | Where FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*' | ft Name, InstanceId -AutoSize
```

Comment: This is the way. (Though it might be technically slower)